# NSData loads in simulator but not on Device

Tags: objective-c, file-io

I'm parsing data from a file if the internet connection is unavailable. When I test this in the iphone simulator it works perfectly. when I switch to the device it fails. When I save and load the data I used the same name with no difference in case. What could be the problem?

```
- (void)parseXMLFileAtURL:(NSString *)URL
{
    events = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

    NSURL *xmlURL = [NSURL URLWithString:URL];

    NSString* xml = [[NSString alloc]initWithContentsOfURL:xmlURL];
    NSData * xmlData = [xml dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]; //[[NSData alloc]initWithContentsOfURL:xmlURL];
    if (xmlData != nil) {
        fileParser = [[NSXMLParser alloc] initWithData:xmlData];
        HBSaveData(xmlData, @"/xml.plist");
        NSLog(@"backup made %@ " ,xmlData);
    } else {
        xmlData = [[[NSData alloc]initWithData:HBLoadData(@"/xml.plist")]retain];

        fileParser = [[NSXMLParser alloc]initWithData:xmlData];
        networkConnected = YES;
        NSLog(@"backup used %@ " ,xmlData);
    }

    [fileParser setDelegate:self];

    [fileParser setShouldProcessNamespaces:NO];
    [fileParser setShouldReportNamespacePrefixes:NO];
    [fileParser setShouldResolveExternalEntities:NO];

    [fileParser parse];

}
```

This is the second issue i've had like this and I don't understand why. I've used this same method of saving files 3 other times and now this time it doesn't want to work. My other question remains unanswered.

Here are the save and load functions

```
static void HBSaveData(NSData *data, NSString* savePath){
    NSString *filePath = pathOfFile(savePath);
    NSString *errString;
    NSData *serialized =
    [NSPropertyListSerialization dataFromPropertyList:data
                                           format:NSPropertyListBinaryFormat_v1_0
                                 errorDescription:&errString];

[serialized writeToFile:savePath atomically:YES];

if (errString)
{
    NSLog(@"%@" ,errString);
    [errString release]; // exception to the rules
}


//[data writeToFile:filePath atomically:YES];
NSLog(@"%@", filePath);
```

}

```
static NSData* HBLoadData(NSString* savePath) {
    NSString *filePath = pathOfFile(savePath);

    NSString *errString;
    NSData *serialized = [NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:savePath];



NSData* data =
[NSPropertyListSerialization propertyListFromData:serialized
                                 mutabilityOption:NSPropertyListMutableContainers
                                           format:NULL
                                 errorDescription:&errString];

if (errString)
{
    NSLog(@"%@" ,errString);
    [errString release]; // exception to the rules
}
return data;
```

}

```
static inline NSString* pathOfFile(NSString * savePath){

NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
NSString *documentsFolder = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
return [documentsFolder stringByAppendingPathComponent:savePath];
```

}

I performed a test and looked at the contents of the file directory at read and write. on the simulator I have this.

2011-03-31 08:05:39.117 AnimeSTL[5992:207]  All documents (
    "myEventId.plist",
    "myEvents.plist",
    "myListEvents.plist",
    "xml.dat"
)

On the device I get this

2011-03-31 08:11:10.019 AnimeSTL[134:307]  All documents (
    "myEventId.plist",
    "myEvents.plist",
    "myListEvents.plist"
)
the file isn't being saved for some reason.

edit:
The write fails so I output the file path anyway. is it because iphones can't handle files of type .dat?

2011-03-31 09:48:50.954 AnimeSTL[196:307]  All documents (
    "myEventId.plist",
    "myEvents.plist",
    "myListEvents.plist"
)
2011-03-31 09:48:50.960 AnimeSTL[196:307] write failed
2011-03-31 09:48:50.962 AnimeSTL[196:307] /var/mobile/Applications/FCB4AA53-5450-495B-A190-930535335301/Documents/xml.dat

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remember that the iOS file system is case sensitive, whereas the Mac OS X file system usually isn't. So if your file is really called "XML.plist" instead of "xml.plist", that'll work on the simulator but not on the device.

Comment: when I save the file it was saved in all lowercase letters so I called it the same way. if you look at both HBSave/Load data the string passed in is the same. The string gets appended in the path of file static function and passed to the save data function. am I somehow changing things? I was pretty sleepy when I did this.

Comment: I found that on the device the file isn't being saved into the documents directory. I decided to call this : NSLog(@" All documents %@", [[NSFileManager defaultManager] directoryContentsAtPath:documentsFolder]); and three of the 4 files appear.

Comment: Looking at your code, you should probably change @"/xml.plist" to just @"xml.plist". -stringByAppendingPathComponent: will take care of inserting the path separator.

Comment: Well I removed the path separator and still no avail. cause it saves the other 3 files in the documents directory but not this one. it would make more sense if both didn't work haha. do you need anymore information?

Comment: I would put this up for bounty but I don't have enough reputation... I really need this solved its the last issue preventing me from updating my app...

Comment: -writeToFile:atomically: returns YES if it succeeds, NO if it fails. You might want to check that return value to see whether the file is being written at all. I see you're already logging the file path, so presumably you know whether the path is what it's supposed to be and you can check whether the file is there. If you get NO from -writeToFile:atomically:, look at the objects that you're serializing, maybe even step all the way through that process. Perhaps you have an object in there that's not a serializable type.

Comment: Okay checking that now. yeah its failing to write to the device. Hmm i'm basically saving the contents of the URL into a string and then encoding the string into data. then passing that data into the save function. which fails to write the data. before I wasn't serializing the data and it wasn't working on either the device or simulator. now its just halfway there...

Comment: If all you're writing is a string, you can write that directly to a file instead of using the data. Look at NSString's -writeToFile:atomically:encoding:error:.

Answer (score 0):

Is `/xml.plist` the full path of your file (xml.plist in the root folder), or is that path being modified in `HBSaveData()`?

If that is the actual path, that's probably your problem – iOS only allows you to write to the filesystem in folders specific to your app.  Look at using `NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains()` to find your app's documents folder.

Comment: I've added the rest of the code involved with saving and loading the data. I don't think i'm modifying the string in any way. or maybe I am?